# style rule not being applied to td element

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I am using a logic to highlight cells based on if the cursor is hovering over the row:

```
function setupTable(tbl) {
    if ($(tbl).find('tbody').size() > 0) {
        $(tbl).find('tbody tr').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('td:gt(0)').addClass('highlight');
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('td:gt(0)').removeClass('highlight');
        }).click(window.onTrClick);

        if ($(tbl).find('tbody tr').size() > 10) {
            setUpPagination(tbl);
        }
    }
}
```

The style rule is define like the follows:

```
.gridview .data
{
    background-color: White;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.highlight
{
    background-color: #3169C6;
    color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But on hovering the text goes white. The net effect is as if that row of data is blanked out. I open IE's developer toolbar. And try to play around.

[image]

I try to manipulate the class attribute and find out that

```
class="data highlight"
```

does not give the desired effect. But if I did

```
class="highlight"
```

it sort of works...

I am trying to understand why this is so? How will the rules be applied if we do

`class="data highlight"`?

---

UPDATE:

I want the padding of `.data` to be sort-of "inherited" (or maintained) to `.highlight`. What do I do then?

Comment: You should have let us know about your update by writing a comment on the answers. I'm only here because I happened to check back on the question. In response to your update: the `padding` on `.data` will also be applied (for an element with `class="data highlight"`), because there is no `padding` on `.highlight` to override it. Or perhaps you should remove the `padding` from `.data`, and do `.data, .highlight { padding: 0 3px }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gridview .data` has [higher specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than `.highlight`.

The result is that `background-color: White` (from `.gridview .data`, instead of `background-color: #3169C6` from `.highlight`) and `color: White` (from `.highlight`) is applied, making it appear to be "blanked out".

**To fix it**, you should change `.highlight` to `.gridview .highlight`.

This fix will work because `.gridview .data` and `.gridview .highlight` will then have equal specificity, so it will then come down to which was defined last. That's `.gridview .highlight`, so the declarations in there will override those in `.gridview .data`.

If you also use the `.highlight` class in other places, then instead change it to `.highlight, .gridview .highlight`.

Comment: thanx. but i think you should put the response for the update in your answer, rather than in the questions comment. And my apologies to those concerned for not intimating about the update myself.

Answer (score 1):

`.gridview .data` have higher priority than `.highlight`

You can read more here
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/